# Swap entity in the JPA listener?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

is it possible to **swap** an **entity being loaded/persisted** via JPA entity **listener** method? What I'm trying to do is to have EntityAListener which would wrap/unwrap EntityA each time it's loaded/persisted and pass it over instead.

That seems impossible from the way they define such methods:

```
public class MyEntityListener {
  @PrePersist void onPrePersist(Object o) {}
  @PostPersist void onPostPersist(Object o) {}
  @PostLoad void onPostLoad(Object o) {}
  @PreUpdate void onPreUpdate(Object o) {}
  @PostUpdate void onPostUpdate(Object o) {}
  @PreRemove void onPreRemove(Object o) {}
  @PostRemove void onPostRemove(Object o) {}
}
```

Do I have to use global listeners? I'm currently using aspects to do that but it isn't so efficient as I cannot pointcut the persist / update method when called with the EntityA?

Comment: you can't change the instance of the object, just change its properties

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to intercept all persist / load methods when called when particular entity?

Comment: well not sure if this is what you asked but you can define all the annotations in the same method, @PrePersist #PostPersist void your method(){}

Comment: Nope, that's not what I asked about. If I cannot use JPA entity listeners to swap that entity it seems that I must stick to Aspects. What I'm asking is that whether there's a way to intercept all JPA load/update calls (on the EntityManager) called with a particular entity?